# print data/values from a list of dictionary which in turn has list and dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries which, in turn, got a list that got a dictionary.
I want to print all the values of each item in a list in a single line. How to get this?
I was unable to get this.
so far u was able to print the data in a set of 2 lines

```
lst1=[
{'key1':'45','key2':'56', 'key3':[{'key4':'43','key5':'64', 'key9': 'ds', 'key10': 'as'},{'key6':'32'}], 'key7':'4r','key8':'h5'},
      {'key1':'ht','key2':'nm', 'key3':[{'key4':'lk','key5':'mm', 'key9': 'bv', 'key10': 'mk'},{'key6':'lo'}], 'key7':'ok','key8':'gh'},
      {'key1':'lp','key2':'ng', 'key3':[{'key4':'lk','key5':'jj', 'key9': 'ds', 'key10': 'kkl'},{'key6':'ki'}], 'key7':'nb','key8':'ip'},
      {'key1':'7y','key2':'jh', 'key3':[{'key4':'45','key5':'cv', 'key9': '3e', 'key10': 'lp'},{'key6':'lm'}], 'key7':'xz','key8':'jg'}]
x=[]

for j in range(len(lst1)):
        x.append(lst1[j]['key3'])
for g in range(len(lst1)):
    print (lst1[g]['key1'], lst1[g]['key7'])
for h in range(len(x)):
            print(x[h][0]['key4'], x[h][0]['key5'], x[h][1]['key6'], x[h][0]['key9'] )
```

current output:

```
45 4r
ht ok
lp nb
7y xz
43 64 32 ds
lk mm lo bv
lk jj ki ds
45 cv lm 3e
```

Please let me know how to get the desired output(last 3 lines to be appended with first 3)

```
45 4r 43 64 32 ds
ht ok lk mk bv mm
lp nb lk jj ki ds
7y xz 45 cv lm 3e
```

I have tried printing the 2nd set inside 1st set loop but that did not work

```
for j in range(len(lst1)):
        x.append(lst1[j]['key3'])
for g in range(len(lst1)):
    print (lst1[g]['key1'], lst1[g]['key7'])
    for h in range(len(x)):
            print(x[h][0]['key4'], x[h][0]['key5'], x[h][1]['key6'], x[h][0]['key9'] )
```

Comment: Could you try writing the code with names and values that appear to mean something? This is abstract and hard to follow.

Comment: "Please let me know how to get the deisred ouput(last 3 lines to be appended with first 3)" What happened to the `ht ok` part?

Comment: What is the rule that tells me that `ht ok` is the line to ignore, instead of one of the other first four lines?

Comment: According to your code, `ht ok` should be output.

Comment: And use `print (lst1[g]['t1'], lst1[g]['t7'], end=' ')` simply.

Comment: i have updated the post to make it clear the requirement

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the desired output with the below :

```
for g in range(len(lst1)):
    print (lst1[g]['key1'], lst1[g]['key7'], x[g][0].get('key4'), x[g][0].get('key5'), x[g][1].get('key6'), x[g][0].get('key9'))
```

```
Output
======
45 4r 43 64 32 ds
ht ok lk mm lo bv
lp nb lk jj ki ds
7y xz 45 cv lm 3e
>>>
```